# Skip pauses when running a batch script from Task Scheduler

Tags: windows-7

I have a batch script that is run on a schedule, and which is sometimes manually run. This script has a `pause` in it so that an `echo`ed message stays visible when the script is run manually - that is, without the pause, the console window automatically closes and the user has no idea why.

I've found solutions [for when one batch script calls another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3585380/1021426), and which involve [passing in an optional parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3583648/1021426) which, if present, the script will skip its pause. Both cases require changing the batch script.

Is there a simple way to run the batch script with pauses disabled or skipped, without changing the script itself? Maybe something like `myBatch.bat --skippauses`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### COUPLE QUICK WAYS TO SKIP BATCH FILE LOGIC FROM RUNNING

***TO START:*** *I'm not familiar with any ways to skip `PAUSE` commands in a batch script (at least in your case to meet your requirements) unless you use one of the two solution I'll list below in thorough detail.  I know of no switches such as `--skippauses` that would accomplish that with such a simple solution in calling or executing a batch script that would just work to skip any or all `PAUSE` commands without changing the actual logic of the batch script beforehand to potentially accept that as an argument to then NOT do a `PAUSE` command, but you would HAVE to make changes to the batch script logic in order for it to work that way.*

**SOLUTION 1 (does not change called batch script file that you call)**

Dynamically build a new dynamically built script MATCHING the logic of the the CALLed script and EXCLUDE all lines containing the `PAUSE` string (case insensitive), and then run the dynamically built script instead with same logic as the CALLed script minus all LINES containing `PAUSE`, and thus any `PAUSE` commands.

Just add something similar to your `myBatch.bat` as my below example and be sure to point directories, etc where those need to be. Essentially, this will run the `FINDSTR /i /v` command against the script you `CALL`, and then read it line-by-line, but EXCLUDE all lines containing the string `PAUSE` which is NOT case sensitive, and pipe that right over to a new dynamically built batch script with a unique name that you then run your `CALL` against.

**EXAMPLE SCRIPT**

```
@ECHO OFF

:: Parse out space from hour part of time and replace with a zero (for hours of 00:00 - 09:59)
SET hh=%TIME:~0,2%
SET hh=%hh: =0%
SET DateString=%DATE:~10,4%%DATE:~4,2%%DATE:~7,2%_%hh%%TIME:~3,2%%TIME:~6,2%
SET DynScriptName=%Temp%\NOPAUSE_%~N0_%DateString%.cmd

:: If DynScriptName already exists, just delete it
IF EXIST "%DynScriptName%" DEL /F /Q "%DynScriptName%"

:: Use FINDSTR to ignore all lines containing "pause" but pipe all other lines to DynScriptName to later CALL/EXECUTE
:: /i switch denotes case insensitivity, /v switch denotes exclude value in results piped to DynScriptName
FINDSTR /i /v "pause" "C:\folder\folder\myBatch.bat">"%DynScriptName%"

:: Call the dynamically built script without PAUSE command lines
CALL "%DynScriptName%"

:: If DynScriptName already exists, just delete it (post cleanup)
IF EXIST "%DynScriptName%" DEL /F /Q "%DynScriptName%"  
GOTO EOF
```

**CONCLUSION:**  This (`Solution 1`)should satisfy your two needs in particular:

1. You have a way to now run a dynamically built script without `PAUSE` commands based on the running a script that dynamically builds a new script against that scripts [contents] logic, per run, but to exclude all `PAUSE` containing lines and thereby eliminating the `PAUSE` commands from running.
2. Also, this ensure the current script which you are running via `CALL` DOES NOT need to be *modified* to accommodate for the requested changes in your inquiry as it just dynamically rebuilds another excluding what you requested.
3. Furthermore, another *simple* solution as in `Solution 2` (below) gives a method to indeed make changes to the script you CALL, if you want to also consider this easy route, you have my `Solution 2` example as well as the other articles for changes needed at that level.

---

**SOLUTION 2 (does change called batch script logic)**

In your script with the `PAUSE` command, you'd put a label on it like the below for example. You'd then put a label on the logic just after the `PAUSE` command so you can add `IF` logic to look for the fist argument passed to the script when it's executed.

Just above the `PAUSE` command label *(meaning* `:PauseLabel` *in my example)*, you'd put the `IF [%1]==[] GOTO PauseLabel` and then the very next line beneath that you'd put `GOTO SkipPause`.

This tells it if the script was executed and NO first argument what passed, then go to `:PauseLabel` and do what's there, which is `PAUSE.` If there is ANY first argument passed, then it will go to `:SkipPause` and do what's next, which is the rest of your logic without the `PAUSE` command.

This way people can run it all day long manually by just double-clicking it (not passing it an argument), but your scheduled job can pass any first argument you want (it's just a dummy argument) to ensure the `IF` logic can just confirm it exists or if it's NULL.

**Script with `PAUSE` command 1st argument check and skip logic example below**

```
<Script logic before PAUSE>

IF [%1]==[] GOTO PauseLabel
GOTO SkipPause

:PauseLabel 
 PAUSE

:SkipPause
 <Rest of your batch logic>
```

**Passing the argument example to your script (where it's scheduled)**

```
myBatch.bat SkipPause
```

Please note that when you schedule the batch the first argument can be `SkipPause`, `dummy`, `DosEquis` or anything else you want it to be. The logic with the `IF` just says, "is there an argument passed to the script when it was executed, and if so, go to `:SkipPause`, if not, go to `:PauseLabel`.

Comment: While this would allow me to skip pauses in the script, you missed my requirement about needing a way to do it *without* modifying the script. I've already seen (a variation of) this solution in a [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583565/how-to-skip-pause-in-batch-file/3583648#3583648).

Comment: It looks like a great workaround (so +1), but it misses the `simple` requirement. I was hoping for something like a command-line argument which uses a built-in way to disable/skip/suppress pauses. And there doesn't seem to be such a feature for Windows console or Task Scheduler.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. If you modify your answer to start off with something like "No, there's no way as simple as `--skippauses`, but here are some workarounds that will accomplish what you described...", I can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this with a very simple solution...

I just use a variable which I set at the top of the file, based on whatever criteria.

For example:

```
if %1==skip set skipPause=1 else skipPause=0
```

Then later in the batch file do something like this:

```
if skipPause=1 pause
```

Very simple and elegant!
(plus you can use it for other things like skipping certain 'echo' statements like this:

```
if skipPause=0 (
   echo I'm doing something now.
   do something
   echo I'm done
   pause
)
```

If "skipPause" is set to 1, no feedback will occur.

Voila!